# Saving/downloading binary (buffer?) as a pdf

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, pdf, hapi.js

User uploads the pdf file which gets saved to **mongo** as a binary, files are small in size (<1mb) so I am not using **GridFS**.

How to download the pdf back? 
Here is what I have tried:
I am extracting the binary from mongo and sending it back to the user. I am using **Hapi**, sending it back goes simply as

```
res(binaryMongoPDF).code(200);
```

I am receiving same data I have store in mongo on the client. According to what I have read I should convert the binary to blob:

```
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
```

I have tried with and without setting `responseType` to `arraybuffer`:

```
$http.get(API_URL + "/cv/me", {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
```

and then just let user download it, I am simplifying that with `Angular FileSave`, but I have also tried with vanilla a tag creation approach:

```
FileSaver.saveAs(r, 'text.pdf');
```

The file I am getting back can't be opened as a pdf.

Something I have observed is that binary file I am saving in mongo has size **73262**, but the blob has size **97426**. I have no idea if this is normal or not.

Comment: What is the `Content-type` header of the response from the API?

Comment: @georgeawg Without me setting it manually - `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`. Setting it to the `"application/pdf"` is not changing anything.

Comment: I am in the same situation. any solution found ?

Answer (score 0):

If the server returns the file as a data url:

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA
```

Use this directive:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("xdHref", function() {
  return function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs) {
     scope.$watch(attrs.xdHref, function(newVal) {
       newVal && elem.attr("href", newVal);
     });
  };
});
```

To set the `href` attribute of an `<a>` tag with the data:

```
<a download="data_{{files[0].name}}" xd-href="data">
  <button>Download data</button>
</a>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/CqIixHWefjYmDfmJPbNF?p=preview)